# The date changes when scraped (using python lxml) and written to csv. How do I prevent this?

Tags: python, csv, lxml

The dates in the site are '14 Aug 1899', '13 Dec 1901' etc. '14 Aug 1899' prints as it is. But '13 Dec 1901' becomes '13 Dec 2001' when scraped from the site and written to csv. The sample code looks like this;

```
url = ['www.example1.com','www.example2.com','www.example3.com' ... 'www.example4.com']
output = csv.writer(open('output_demo.csv','wb',))
output.writerow('Name', 'Start Date')
for page in url:
    startdate = []
    name = []
    content = lxml.html.parse(page)
    name_n = content.xpath('//tr[@class="data1"]/td[1]')
    start_d = content.xpath('//tr[@class="data1"]/td[2]') # extracting the date
    sdate = [sd.text for sd in start_d]
    name_list = [na.text for na in name_n]
    startdate.append(sdate)
    name.append(name_list)
    zipped = zip(name,startdate)
    for row in zipped:
        output.writerow(row) # writing 'date' and 'name'
        zipped = None
```

Here's the [site](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;orderby=start;page=52;template=results;type=batting;view=innings)

Comment: Please provide a link or a sample html content with this dates.

Comment: here's the site http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;orderby=start;page=52;template=results;type=batting;view=innings

Comment: I don't think that the date changes, rather that you are extracting multiple Xpaths and that their order is different than what you expect it to be. Take a closer look at `sdate`.

Comment: @rkrzr Actually that works fine. The issue happens when the date is being written to csv.

Comment: @richie: I'm a little surprised this code runs.  When I try it, the first `writerow` fails.  When I fix that, it doesn't seem to get the right data.  Finally, you're making two lists, `sdate` and `name_list`, and then instead of zipping them directly you're appending them to two other lists, making two lists of one element, and then writing that out, so that should only give you one data row (which is what it does for me.)  Are you sure this is the code you're running?

Comment: Am I missing the point here?  Where's code which translates the date?  From the code's point of view there are only strings, or am I wrong?  (And strings will probably never be translated from "13 Dec 1901" to "13 Dec 2001".)

Comment: Could it be that this is a ghost bug?  (One that's not really there but just appears to be.)  I guess you check the contents of the `csv` result file by opening it with a `csv` aware editor (Excel or sth) which automatically understands and converts dates (and by this makes an error).  Could this be the case?

Comment: @Alfe Yes I check the contents of the csv with Excel. Correct. How do I handle that now?

Comment: @DSM That was sample code. My original code runs. The point of the sample code is just for everyone to see how the date is being handled. I know that date is at td[12] and I have to import csv and lxml :)

Comment: @richie try looking at the file with a text editor. If the content is correct there, then Excel was just trying to be "helpful".

Comment: Check not with Excel.  It interferes too much.  Check using `less` or `notepad` or whatever text editor you've got.  Probably you won't see the error there.

Comment: @rkrzr You are right! The date is correct when I view in Sublime Text.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see any problems with dates. FYI, I've made some improvements to the code:

```
import csv
from lxml import html


url = ['http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;orderby=start;page=52;template=results;type=batting;view=innings']

output = csv.writer(open('output_demo.csv', 'wb'))
output.writerow(['Name', 'Start Date'])
for page in url:
    content = html.parse(page)
    rows = content.xpath('//tr[@class="data1"]')
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.getchildren()
        name = cells[0].find('a').text
        start_date = cells[11].find('b').text
        output.writerow([name, start_date])
```

The contents of `output_demo.csv` after running the code:

```
Name,Start Date
WM Bradley,17 Jul 1899
W Brockwell,17 Jul 1899
Hon.FS Jackson,14 Aug 1899
TW Hayward,14 Aug 1899
KS Ranjitsinhji,14 Aug 1899
CB Fry,14 Aug 1899
AC MacLaren,14 Aug 1899
CL Townsend,14 Aug 1899
WM Bradley,14 Aug 1899
WH Lockwood,14 Aug 1899
AO Jones,14 Aug 1899
AFA Lilley,14 Aug 1899
W Rhodes,14 Aug 1899
J Worrall,14 Aug 1899
H Trumble,14 Aug 1899
VT Trumper,14 Aug 1899
MA Noble,14 Aug 1899
J Darling,14 Aug 1899
SE Gregory,14 Aug 1899
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll have to go with your approach to extract the dates.